# Showing values from a external REST service

Tags: xpages

I would like to enter a value in a field and retrieve related information from a REST service provider. How should I approach this in an xpage?

For example, typing a product name should be the input for a REST call to the third part provider I alread have access to and get all the relevant information in JSON/XML. I have looked at the REST Control in xpage and not sure how to make it look at a third party URL. It seems to only look at domino objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The REST Control from the extension library is to provide a REST service, not consume one. Dojo has methods for consuming a REST service, namely the xhrGet and xhrPost methods. Here's a link to [xhrGet](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/xhrGet.html). Then use the value from the field you were speaking about to build the URL to your 3rd party REST service.

Answer (score 0):

@Keithstric is right. Use Dojo to read REST from other URLs. You might need to use the [Domino Proxy](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/inotes-full/index.html) to comply with JavaScript same origin policies.